# REGEX - Get all groups of characters with their delimiter

Tags: regex

I'm not pretty good with regex sot his is my problem.

I have a String who contains `c#m#fc#fm#` and I want to get all groups of characters with their # at the end.
Like this :

```
c#
m#
fc#
fm#
```

I have try some regex but I never get what I want.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Much easier thing to do would be, to split the string by the character '#' and then get every group and add a '#'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[^#]+#` and find all matches, where match will start by capturing one or more characters using negated character class `[^#]+` (any character except `#`) and at the end will match one `#`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rxcEAB/1/)**

Also, in case you have space in your string which you don't want to include in matched texts, you can put `\s` also within the negated character class and use this regex,

```
[^#\s]+#
```

**[Regex Demo excluding space from matched tokens](https://regex101.com/r/rxcEAB/2/)**

Comment: Woh :o It was so simple, my regex tests took a lot of things xD. THanks a lot it's working !